# Обработка ajax запросов в mvc структуре

Tags: php, ajax, ооп, mvc

Столкнулся с проблемой и никак не могу продумать логику работы. На данный момент я использую mvc структуру. Все работает как нужно данные поступают в контроллер, затем отправляются в модель, обрабатываются, возвращаются обратно и выдаются клиенту. Все просто. Но никак не могу придумать, как правильно настроить работу ajax запросов. Их у меня будет очень много. Один из вариантов это создать единый ajax контроллер, на который будут поступать все запросы и там обрабатываться. Но я хочу сделать, чтобы обработка происходила непосредственно в активном контроллере и данные бы обрабатывались в активной модели.

Пример контроллера:

```
    class Controller_Main extends Controller
{
    
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new Model_Main();
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    function action_index()
    {
        $data = array(
            'content' => $this->model->content(),
        );
        $this->view->generate('main.php', 'template.php', $data);
    }
}
```

Пример модели:

```
<?php
class Model_Main extends Model
{
    public function content()
    {
        $news = DB::run("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 6");
        return $news;
    }
}
```

То есть тут мы выводим все новости на странице. Как сюда можно внедрить ajax запрос, точнее как его тут обрабатывать. Если я хочу допустим сортировать не по ид, а по названию.

Вот скрипт отправки:

```
$(document).on('change', '#main_sort', function(e){

    let select = document.getElementById('sort_by_main');
    var data = JSON.stringify({ "method":"POST","select":select.value,'action': 'sort','module':'main' });
    goSend(data);
});

function goSend(data) {
    let url = "/main";
    let method = JSON.parse(data).method;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        //ответ
        result = JSON.parse(this.response);
      
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Меня интересует как правильно по такой структуре сделать обработку ajax запросов и правильно ли я вообще делаю? Возможно есть решения куда лучше этого. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Controller занимается обработкой запроса, Model получает данные, View рендерит ответ - по mvc все ок)

> Один из вариантов это создать единый ajax контроллер, на который будут поступать все запросы и там обрабатываться.

Нет, так делать не нужно. Обычно, в том же laravel роуты разделены, и это сделано как минимум по 2-м причинам:

1. Запросы к api обрабатываются точно так же как и "обычные" запросы. Тут разница только в формате ответа.
2. Способ авторизации. При запросах к api, не нужно использовать сессии/куки, так как мобильные устройства не могут использовать ваш api. Решением может быть OAuth, JWT ну или просто отдать пару токенов access + refresh з каким-то ttl.

> мобильные устройства - это очень грубо, более правильно будет сказать, все
> устройства в которых нет хранилища под сессии как в браузере.

Исходя из выше сказанного, сделаем небольшой итог:
1 Controller может иметь много методов, а значит, может обрабатывать много запросов. Каждый метод Controller обрабатывает 1 роут. Как правило, Controller имеет CRUD методы какой-то entity.

Пример:

```
    class UserController {
    /**
     * Return collection of users
     */
    public function index() {}

    /**
     * Return user by ID
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function show(int $id) {}

    /**
     * Patch user property
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function change(Request $request) {}

    /**
     * Update user
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function update(Request $request) {}

    /**
     * Create a new user
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {}

    /**
     * Delete a user by ID
     *
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function destroy(int $id) {}
}
```

У каждого метода класса есть свой http метод:

```
Метод в классе | Http метод
index          | GET
show           | GET
change         | PATCH
update         | PUT
store          | POST
destroy        | DELETE
```

Как видно из примера, Controller относиться к entity User, а все его методы к действию над этой entity.

По такому принципу работает api в framework-ках (возможно с небольшими отличиями в конкретно взятому framework-у).

> То есть тут мы выводим все новости на странице. Как сюда можно внедрить ajax запрос, точнее как его тут обрабатывать.

Это очень абстрактно, уж очень. Так как каждый проект имеет свою бизнес-логику. Собственно ajax запрос Вы внедрили, но более правильно было бы понимать зачем это делается. По поводу обработки - все зависит от того что используете (React, Vue, Angular, или ужасный JQuery). У Вашем случае это JQuery. Бог миловал, я с ним не работал))

> Если я хочу допустим сортировать не по ид, а по названию.

Можно просто применить фильтр на js, тогда ваш api должен отдать всю коллекцию записей, но это справедливо больше для SPA. Если же, сортировать те 6 записей - крутите js))

повторюсь: вторая часть вопроса очень абстракта, и можно там рассуждать много. Определитесь с бизнесовыми задачами, и задавайте конкретный вопрос, если они у Вас еще есть.

**Итог**: по бекенд части, постарался в кратце описать как устроена api. Очень упрощено, так как не сказано про middleware, Rate-Limit, CORS и т.д.

По JQuery - я Вам к сожалению не советчик)

Comment: Спасибо, Я понял, буду углубляться в эту тему.